# Lambda Web API returning 403 for verbs other than POST

Tags: aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, aws-sam

I have created a Serverless Lambda Web API using a built-in template. The web api is deployed to AWS using CloudFormation and everything is working fine (i.e. All GET, POST etc).

I have then checked the resources created by CloudFormation and created all of the resources using Terraform. I have double checked and REST API in the API Gateway, Lambda, Lambda permissions and triggers are exactly the same when created from both serverless template and terraform scripts.

The issue is the when using the resources created from Terraform, I am not able to call the Web API using HTTP verb other then POST. Below is my terraform script for the API Gateway.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest" {
  name        = "SimulationServer"
  description = "Terraform Serverless Application Example"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api_gw_proxy_resource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "api_gw_proxy_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_gw_proxy_resource.id
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "api_gw_proxy_integration" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.api_gw_proxy_method.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.api_gw_proxy_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "ANY"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.SimulationServer.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "api_gw_proxy_root_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.id
  resource_id   = 
aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.root_resource_id
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "api_gw_proxy_root_integration" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.api_gw_proxy_root_method.resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.api_gw_proxy_root_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "ANY"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.SimulationServer.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_gw_deployment" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.api_gw_proxy_integration,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.api_gw_proxy_root_integration,
  ]
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.SimulationServer_api_gateway_rest.id
  stage_name  = var.env
}

output "base_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.api_gw_deployment.invoke_url
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be very strange but simple solution.
Instead of using,

```
integration_http_method = "ANY"
```

When I used,

```
integration_http_method = "POST"
```

Then it started working for all HTTP Verbs (GET, POST, PUT etc)